# Is Design specification is discussed in SRS document?

Tags: srs

[image]

This question was asked in GATE 2015 CSE, I think design specs should not be discussed in SRS.

Answer (score 0):

Ans: (C) Design specifications should not be discussed in the SRS. Instead, they are reserved for the SDD(Software design description).

A SRS does discuss (A) (B) and (D).

Answer (score 0):

SRS document **does not** contain design specifications. It mainly contains the following things:

- Functional/Non Functional Requirement
- Scope
- Targeted Audience
- Purpose
- UML Diagrams which will be base on the requirement